# Getting started with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I just started my laravel course with laracast. I dont quite understand yet all the enviornment-related things.

I know that Composer is a kind of a program that downloads pre-written scripts to use in your project. But where does it work? On my local machine or on my vagrant homestead box VM? On which of these is it supposed to be installed?

I installed myself vagrant homestead box already but does it contain composer? When I go ssh into my guest machine and go to vagrant@homestead:/vagrant$ path I can see composer.json and composer.lock files, but does it mean that I have composer installed?

Answer (score 4):

Composer is a PHP package manager, like npm for javascript or pip for python. There are many examples of package managers. It's useful, because adding dependencies to your php projects can be a pain, but composer makes it really easy. You just add the dependency to `composer.json` and you can use it right off the bat.

Composer isn't laravel specific, you can use it in any php project, laravel uses it to manage it's dependencies, laravels dependencies use it to manage their dependencies and so forth.

If nothing else, the composer autoloader is great, so you can use it even if you don't plan on using external packages.

Homestead should come with composer installed. A `composer.lock` file is generated when you run a composer install or composer update. If you plan on creating or using other php projects on your machine, it's probably a good idea to have composer installed on your machine as well.

Comment: Okay, so I just tried to install Composer on my machine with Composer-Setup.exe but it asks me to locate php.exe. The problem is that php is included in my homestead VM so I don't know how to access it. Should I install php on my local machine as well? But what's the point, if the reason to having homestead is to keep your local machine clean of any server-related stuff.

Comment: Yes, composer requires php to run. The choice is up to you. Vagrant provides  a very good way to keep your computer clean, and if that's important to you, you shouldn't install it on your computer. Just keep in mind that to use composer, you'll need to be on a vm (such as homestead). It's ultimately a personal choice. I like to keep it on my machine for convenience. If you prefer less clutter, work on vms.

Comment: Can I have php installed both on my local machine and VM? Won't it collide anyhow? The "getting started" part of laracast course isn't very clear to me and I want to follow everything just as they do, not to get lost when I'm further into the course. So just for sake of that, I feel like installing it onto my machine as well.

Comment: Yes, you can have it installed on your local machine as well. They won't interfere with each other in any way. Vagrant vms only have the one shared folder through which you share files, and the open ports, everything else acts as though they were separate machines.